# php - Create adodb db2 loader in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, connection, db2, loader, adodb

can anybody helpme to create adodb loader for db2 database in codeigniter. I've try to use some library and it work for oracle database, but now i'm confuse of connecting my new codeigniter application to IBM DB2. This the adodbloader for oracle.

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    Class Adodbloader{
        function Adodbloader(){
            if ( !class_exists('ADONewConnection') )
                require_once(BASEPATH.'/system/libraries/adodb/adodb.inc.php');

            $obj =& get_instance();
            $this->_init_adodb_library($obj); 
        } 

        function _init_adodb_library(&$ci) {
            $db_var = false; 
            $debug = false; 

            if (!isset($dsn)) {
                // fallback to using the CI database file 
                include(APPPATH.'config/database'.EXT); 
                $group = 'default'; 
                $dsn = 'oci8://my_dbusername:my_dbpassword@my_dbhostname/my_oracledb'; 
            } 

            // $ci is by reference, refers back to global instance
            $ci->adodb =& ADONewConnection($dsn);

            if ($db_var) {
                // also set the normal CI db variable
                $ci->db =& $ci->adodb; 
            } 

            if ($debug) {
                $ci->adodb->debug = true;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

The manual connection in adodb for db2 look like this:

```
    include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
    $dbms   = 'odbc_db2';
    $db =& ADONewConnection($dbms);
    $dsn = "driver={IBM db2 odbc DRIVER};Database=MY_DBNAME;hostname=MY_DBHOST;port=50000;protocol=TCPIP;"."uid=MYDBUSERNAME; pwd=MY_DBPASSWORD";
    $db->Connect($dsn);
```

My questions now, how to use that manual adodb db2 connection to integrate with codeigniter, so that i can use variable $db on all my application model.
Thanks for everybody who give me a solutions about my problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this as well but it seems from the CI documentation that you cannot override, extend, or replace database classes.

See this page: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

When I step through the code it looks like there are a lot of hard-coded path and class names in /system/database/DB.php.

I'd love to be proven wrong, though.